# Accessing Public Datasets in BigQuery - not adding to left hand explorer pane

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-public-datasets

I'm pretty new to both SQL and BigQuery but when I follow the directions for accessing a public data set seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-rZd5DwEww AND https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgoSIzkZv9c&t=89s

The data set does not add to the left hand Explorer Pane for me to access.

I have tried clicking View Data Set from both the Explorer Panel and the Marketplace tab. It brings over an overview tab of the data set info, but it does not appear as bigquery-public-data on the left hand panel.

Answer (score 3):

Sharing how I resolved the problem of BigQuery not showing the public data results in the Explorer windowpane. I got the idea to try it from [this site](https://www.optimizesmart.com/how-to-access-bigquery-public-data-sets/)

the previous responses were correct, but I could not follow what they meant by doing the "public" search.

TLDR - after searching "public", pin the "bigquery-public-data" so all data sets you will query will be under it.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit the gcp marketplace and select an dataset
https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace
https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/united-states-census-bureau/acs

Here press the blue button "View Dataset" and a window with Big Query will open.

[image]

Here in Big Query the dataset should appear on the left side; most public datsets are in the project  `bigquery-public-data`.

Projects can be pinned directly on the left panel by entering the project name. Please click on the yellow marked buttons:
[image]

The project name can be obtained by a sample query on the dataset. Open any sample query and look for

```
FROM `bigquery-public-data.census_bureau_acs.censustract_2010_5yr`
```

The project name is here the text between the back quotation and the point, also :`bigquery-public-data`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, that didn't seem to work either. I think it was actually a bug on Google's end because I created a new sandbox account under a different email and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, follow the following step:

1. Instead of the explore dataset option, use the search pane, search for public
   [image]
2. Click on Broaden search to all projects and the click on the pin button to pin the public dataset
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing as samuel and it works just go to one of the other datasets and then copies the dataset ID in this case its  bigquery-public-data.census_bureau_acs

paste this to the explorer panels and then click broaden your search to all project then just click pin and it will pin it to your existing project

Answer (score 0):

As of December 2022, none of the answers here worked for me. I tried a bunch of things and found that the only way to get access to public datasets was to

#### 1 - Click on the view dataset:[image: click view dataset]

#### 2 - Copy the Dataset ID into the search field:

[image: add dataset id to search field]

#### 3 - Broaden the search

[image]

#### 4 - And finally, star the specific table(s) I wanted to access.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Yes for this I found the answer in a discussion forum. You need to add search for " Public" in the "Explorer" search bar. When the results come in as "Found 0 results" click " Broaden search to all projects" and it should populate the data. I hope that helps!

Comment: [**Attribution Required**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required): As the answer was provided elsewhere ("*I found the answer in a discussion forum*"), ensure that it is [referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) accordingly by doing "*all of the following*": 1) "*Provide a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links) to the original page or answer*" 2) "*[Quote](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) only the relevant portion*" 3) "*Provide the name of the original author*"